# Как собрать из json Html?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Аяксом занимаюсь неделю. Как при помощи `jQuery` собрать `HTML`.
То есть нужно, что бы скрипт читал `JSON`, видел, например, item `JSON`-a, собирал `HTML` и вставлял данные из `JSON` в собранные `DOM` элементы, которые jquery собирает, когда видит `JSON`.

Ниже представлен `JSON`, который я сделал, а чуть ниже `HTML`-структура, которая должна из него получиться.

```
{ 
"works-item":{ 
    "item":{ 
        "title":"Limited <br>для VAZ", 
        "image-data":"VAZ", 
    } 
    "item":{ 
        "title":"Limited <br>в BAZ", 
        "image-data":"BAZ", 
    }
}
```

```
<div id="cases" class="c-works">
    <h2 class="work-header" style="display: none;"></h2>
    <div class="box_skvere">
        <img data-url="worksVAZ" src="img/works/VAZ.jpg">
        <h3>Limated <br>для VAZ</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box_skvere"> 
        <img data-url="worksBAZ" src="img/works/BAZ.jpg">
        <h3>Limited <br>в BAZ</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

То есть, грубо говоря, в Html изначально ничего нет, все собирается после прочтения и парсинга json-a. И количество собранных дом-элементов должно соответствовать количеству элементов в json.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, кто знает.

Comment: что вы сделали для решения своей проблемы? С чем столкнулись?

Answer (score 1):

Так а что именно вызывает затруднение? у вас есть json объект, структура которого заранее известна.

например вот такой:

```
var json = {item:{ type: "div", class:"main" id:"div_id", text: "контент" }}
```

Теперь вам надо из этого объекта создать HTML разметку. Можно так:

```
$( "<div/>", {
        class : json.item.class,
        id: json.item.id
    } ).appendTo( *куда этот элемент будет вставлен* );
```

Содержимое если нужно что то вставить в блок:

```
    $( "<div/>", { class : json.item.class, id: json.item.id } ).html( json.item.text).appendTo( *куда этот элемент будет вставлен* );
```

В результате вы получите вот такую конструкцию:

```
<div class="main" id="div_id">контент</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно для упрощения жизни в этих случаях используют шаблоны. Можно конечно все руками написать (генерацию html) но это будет очень утомительно, черевато ошибками, и это тяжелее поддерживать.

Например на [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) (полный код для твоего примера):

```js
var json = {
  "works-item": [{
    "title": "Limited <br>для VAZ",
    "image-data": "VAZ",
  }, {
    "title": "Limited <br>в BAZ",
    "image-data": "BAZ",
  }]
};

var source = $("#div-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source, {
  noEscape: true
});

var html = template(json);
$("#insert-pos").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="insert-pos"></div>

<script id="div-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div id="cases" class="c-works">
    <h2 class="work-header" style="display: none;"></h2>
    {{#each works-item}}
    <div class="box_skvere">
      <img data-url="works{{image-data}}" src="img/works/{{image-data}}.jpg" />
      <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала убедитесь в валидности вашего Json например здесь http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Когда составите Json объект безошибочно, Вам необходимо пройтись по нему и вывести нужные свойства или сформировать html блок и уже потом его вывести в нужное место. пример:

```
itemsJson.forEach(function (item, i) {
    $("#resultDiv").val(item.title); //решетка это ИД дива для вывода
    //или так
    $("#resultDiv").html("<div class='div-center'><h4>" + item.title + "</h4><br><br><br>");
}
```

Comment: к сож. не весь мой код добавился в ответ, к тому же еще не подсветился(( Очень неудобный здесь редактор, по сравнению с кибрформумом к сож(

Comment: выделить код и нажать кнопку `{ }` на тулбаре, конечно, очень неудобно )

Comment: кстати также советую автору вопроса рассмотреть возможность применения js шаблонов, например очень хорош http://www.embeddedjs.com/